# how can i remove Lenovo thinkcentre m93p bios administrator password

Tags: bios, passwords, administrator, thinkcentre

I have a thinkcentre m93p. I don't know administrator password. Maybe it is default password. I want to install windows 10 via usb but i can't open boot menu because bios ask me password but i don't know.
I removed bios battery for 10-15 minutes. I put back. It is not work. How can i remove/reset bios password?

Answer (score 3):

I found a CMOS restart switch then I followed the instructions
on page 91 of the [Lenovo ThinkCentre M93/p Tiny User Guide](http://www.lenovo.com/shop/americas/content/user_guides/m93p_tiny_ug_en.pdf):

> This section provides instructions on how to erase lost or forgotten
>   passwords, such as a user password.
>
> To erase a lost or forgotten password, do the following:
>
> 1. Remove all media from the drives and turn off all attached devices
>      and the computer.  Then, disconnect all power cords from electrical
>      outlets and disconnect all cables that are connected to the computer.
> 2. Remove the computer cover. See “Removing the computer cover” on page 53.
> 3. Locate the Clear CMOS /Recovery jumper on the system board. 
>      See “Locating parts on the system board” on page 13.
> 4. Move the jumper from the standard position (pin 1 and pin 2)
>      to the maintenance position (pin 2 and pin 3).
> 5. Reinstall the computer cover and connect the power cord. 
>      See “Completing the parts replacement” on page 78.
> 6. Turn on the computer and leave it on for approximately 10 seconds. 
>      When you hear short beeps, turn off the computer by holding the power switch
>      for approximately five seconds.
> 7. Repeat step 1 through step 2.
> 8. Move the Clear CMOS /Recovery jumper back to the standard position
>      (pin 1 and pin 2).
> 9. Reinstall the computer cover and connect the power cord. 
>      See “Completing the parts replacement” on page 78.

Figure 4 “System board part locations” appears on page 13:

[image: Figure 4. System board part locations]

The Clear CMOS (Complementary Metal Oxide Semiconductor) /Recovery jumper
is item 6.